# How to use VBA in PowerPoint to attach an OLE Object to an Outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook, powerpoint, email-attachments

I have an embedded OLE object in a PowerPoint slide and I am trying to make a macro that will open Outlook with the OLE object automatically added as an attachment.

The OLE object (a pdf) was inserted into the slide using the normal insert>object>create from file>display as icon method, so it appears as a little pdf icon on the slide from which I would like to launch the macro.

I have figured out the basic VBA for opening Outlook, displaying a new message and all of that, but I can't quite get the attachment to work.  Here is the code I'm working with:

```
Sub SendEmailwithAttachment()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Dear []:<br>" & _
          "<br><br>Attached is .<br>" & _
          "<br><br>Let me know if you have any questions.<br>" & _
          "<br><br>Thank you,"

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = strbody 
    .Attachments.Add (ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Attachment"))
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I had previously used the exact same code to attach a file through a file path, and everything worked perfectly.  But now I need to embed the file in the PowerPoint instead of merely directing the code to attach from the file path.

Both PowerPoint and Outlook are 2010.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model does not allow to add embedded OLE attachments.

Comment: Dmitry- thanks for clarifying, I was not aware of that.  Are there any work arounds?  Or any other ideas for how I could accomplish the goal of automating the attachment of an embedded file?

Comment: Can you save the PDF as a file? You can then pass the file name to Attachments.Add.

Comment: Dmitry- It has to be from the embedded file.  Do you think it would be possible, as a workaround, to temporarily save the embedded file then use that temp file as an attachment?

Comment: I don't know much about PowerPoint, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste an oleObect into Outlook using WordEditor method.  Body and htmlBody are the other two methods to work with Outlook body.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/inspector-wordeditor-property-outlook

Of course an oleObject that is linked rather than embedded might be another matter.